# InfluxDB max available expiration and performance concerns

Tags: backup, restore, influxdb

I develop my metrics based on influxdb. I want to keep the data forever therefore my retention policy is set to inf and my shard retention policy is set to 100 years (the max I could set).

My main concern has to do with degrading performance by keeping this data. My series will not be more than 100000 (as adviced for the low server specs).
Is there gonna be an impact on the memory used indexing wise? More specific memory used by influxdb regardless of issuing any actions such as queries/continoues queries
Also in case there is a problem with performance, is it possible to backup only the data that are bound to be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [InfluxDB Hardware sizing guidelines](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/guides/hardware_sizing/), in moderate load situation with a single node InfluxDB deployed on a server with these specifications: CPU:6 cores and RAM:8-32 GB; you can have 250k writes per second and about 25 queries per second. These numbers will definitely meet your requirements. Also by increasing CPU and RAM you can achieve better performance.
Note, If the scale of your work grew in the future, you can also use "continues query" for down-sampling old data; or export a part of data to a backup file.